# How to run makeglossaries-lite with MiKTeX

Tags: compiling, glossaries

I am currently acquainting myself with the [`glossaries`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) package. Since I don't have a Perl installation yet, I wanted to try using it with `makeindex` first (*Option 2* in the manual). The manual claims, that I can call `makeglossaries-lite` instead of `makeglossaries` in order to automatically call `makeindex` with the right options without a Perl installation.

However, Windows does not know any program called `makeglossaries-lite`. (It does know `makeglossaries`, which rightly tells me that it can't find the script engine when run.)

The file `makeglossaries-lite.lua` exists in `<miktex-installation>/scripts/glossaries/` (alongside `glossaries.perl` and `makeglossaries`).

Why can't I run `makeglossaries-lite`? Is some further setup (e.g. of the Lua engine) required?

Comment: make a bug report at the miktex github site.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I wasn't sure this was a bug. But if you say so, I will file a bug report.

Comment: REQUIRES **texlua** and makeindex or xindy (depending on glossaries package options). most likely needs shell-escape active

Comment: @KJO: I think you misunderstand. I can't call `makeglossaries-lite` _from the command line_. (`makeindex` works fine, as do `makeglossaries` and `xindy`, but those require Perl.)

Comment: @KJO: I don't see what you mean. I am not trying to call `makeglossaries-lite` from inside TeX (or LuaLaTeX). `glossaries` is installed and thus `makeglossaries-lite.lua` is present, I just can't call it from the command line.

Comment: Helps if you supply a mwe with the embeded definitions then I can test the comment that in your scenario no perl without tex live symbolic link it needs 3 separate invocations of makeindex

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that sentence. I have filed a bug report to the developers regarding this and for now they haven't told me that this is intended, so right now I assume that the issue is a (unintentionally) missing executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [bug](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/99) has been fixed, they added the executable `makeglossaries-lite.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to invoke MiKTeX makeglosaries-lite.lua using different texlua syntax without success. (Having tried a dozen or so ways that is not to say it is impossible using some other)

Tex Live for windows does have a precompiled version so it is a simple oneline call to replace the normal three or four makeindex calls needed without using perl.

The replacement set of commands for MiKTeX is currently

```
pdflatex test
makeindex -s test.ist -o test.gls -t test.glg test.glo
makeindex -s test.ist -o test.acr -t test.alg test.acn
makeindex -s test.ist -o test.als -t test.slg test.slo
optionally if you used glossaries extra
    makeindex -s test.ist -o test.gls-abr -t test.glg-abr test.glo-abr
pdflatex test
```

As Ulrike mentioned it would be good if MiKTeX included a variant of makeglossaries-lite.exe similar to W32TeX and Tex Live